# How to use Qt webEngine instead of Qt webkit

Tags: windows, qt, qtwebengine, qt5.4, qt5.8

I added to .pro file `QT +=  webenginewidgets`, but qmake give me error:

```
:-1: error: Unknown module(s) in QT: webenginewidgets
```

I would like to port project from 5.4.0 to 5.8.0.

EDIT: I have read that I can't use MinGW for the web engine with Qt, and should use VS 2015 but I don't know how to use it yet.

I found this package
[Qt VS Package](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=havendv.QtPackage), but there are very contradictory comments.

Comment: Have you enabled this module when you did the installation?

Comment: yes i enabled it.

Comment: What platform are you using?

Comment: windows.
i have read that i can't use MinGW for the web engine, and i should use for it VS 2015, but how to do it didn't understand yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install either [Visual Studio 2015 or the C++ Build Tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/).

The second option is lighter in terms of download and space taken on your machine.

You don't need the VS editor at all if you want to stay with Qt Creator and in this case the VS plugin is not needed.

Comment: C++ Build Tools this version have problems with installation. 
Thank you for advice.

Comment: have you checked the second option, the link is no longer working

Comment: Link has been fixed but you have to look deeper in the page.